# how to install a program for all users on Windows 8?

Tags: installation, windows-8

when I install stuff under built-in Administrator - the other users cannot see the changes. for example I changed VS2012 install - added Blend and few other features - and they are invisible under another user - my 'Microsoft account' ...

I surely don't want this kind of behavior. Can it be changed?

**EDIT: I want those apps 'legitimately installed' for all users so I can use Search and see them on my Start screen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on each program's individual installation program. Some provide an option to install the application for all users or only the current user.

However, you might still be able to use the applications under other user accounts.

Generally, application files are installed to `C:\Program Files\` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\` for 32-bit programs on 64-bit Windows). You might be able to find the application executable file in there and you can create a desktop shortcut simply by dragging the icon to the desktop with the right mouse button and clicking "Create shortcut here":

[image]

Comment: I know how to do that. If you go like that you are not using W8 features - in that case I might rollback to W7 as well. you cant search and you don't have that app on the start screen.. whats the point?

Comment: @Bobb - The problem would exist on Windows 7 also.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click while in the Start screen a taskbar appears at the bottom with an "All apps" button.

Click on that and you can see all the apps available.

Right click on any app icon and the bottom taskbar appears with a button for "Pin to Start", most also have a button for "Pin to taskbar", which applies to the desktop taskbar.